# How to add a unit test project to my existing asp.net core project?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, asp.net-core

I started an asp.net core project using VS code(which is a very powerful lightweight text editor). I want to add a unit test project to my already existing project. In visual studio, I did this by creating a new project under my solution. In vs code I can only create a new directory, how should I add the unit test project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use dotnet CLI to generate a new test project, under your project root folder use one of these commands :

```
dotnet new nunit
dotnet new xunit
dotnet new mstest
```

Comment: which of those testing frameworks would you recommend?

Comment: @NebexElias Personally, I prefer NUnit.

Comment: Is it ok to add unit test folder inside my root project directory?

Comment: @NebexElias That's ok, but it's better you separate it with your root project.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try to run the tests: Program has more than one entry point defined" for console apps containing xUnit tests